# Bezier curve not changing animation movement?

Tags: animation, rigging

Here is something I made:

[image]

The animation is very jagged and I want to make it fluid. I tried changing the interpolation mode in the graph mode to bezier but it didn't change anything :(

Thanks!

[image]

Here is the graph view!

Comment: Could you please take a screen shot of the time line, and the graph editor. The gif is great, but if it could include those, we could help you better.

Comment: No problem! I've added it :)

Comment: Thanks. I see it was already answered. I made gifs to demonstrate, and I'm not that good at that yet, so it took me a long time. :P

Comment: Both answers explain things so well Dx Its a pity I can't mark two as answers!

Comment: Yeah, his is fuller and has more info, so it's good that you chose his. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion.

Reduce the number of keyframes.  You have not shown your frames per second.

Consider having a IK target to have a [Follow Path Constraint].  Paths can be infinitely smooth ... only limited by your frames per second. Insert Keyframes beginning with 2 only. Search Follow Path Constraint here at BSE.

See the addon Simplify Curves.

Do one of 2 actions to archive your current keyframes.

- Archive your file. Copy the file.
- Create a scene which is a copy of the first scene.

Move your keyframes further down the timeline beginning at frame 50. You can also delete the current set of keyframes to live dangerously.

The result should be no keyframes between frame 1 and frame 40.

Next insert 2 keyframes only at frame 1 and frame 40 and judge whether or not it looks choppy.  Consider adding two more  keyframes and again judge whether it looks choppy.  Slowly increase your number of keyframes to see the tension between controlled movement and an excess of keyframes.  If you have both the new and improved keyframes and the old keyframes you can compare them in the playback.

Only you can judge whether or not something is smooth and fluid, at least with your Blender Animation.  We do not know whether the animation is intended to be karate or the Balshoi Ballet.

Know that IK Inverse Kinematics can sometimes produces a sudden rotation. Poles are meant to control this.

Comment: Oh I get it! I cannot have the interpolation mode take effect if there are no frames for it to interpolate, so I need some space between my frames! I get it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try **reducing the number of keyframes.**

- If you have **too many keyframes** *(unless they are placed carefully)* your animation will look choppy. *Try to avoid having consecutive keyrames where the object is in the same location*. Between those two keyframes the object ***will not move***, then it will "jerk" to the next location. On the dope sheet you can find these areas by looking for orange bars. (Those two small sections where there are no orange bars are the frames in which the move will take place.)

[image]

That animation looks like this.

[image]

You can delete the duplicate keyframes,

[image]

And then the animation looks like this.

[image]